# Endless "Hot swap" with Intellij and JRebel

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jrebel

I have Intellij debugging a Java web app in Tomcat 7 with JRebel. Also, Intellij is set to do "hot deploy on frame deactivation". (all latests versions)

Most of the time this configuration works like a charm and I get JRebel to hot swap everything fine.
However, sometimes Intellij will hang in "hot swap" every time the project gets recompiled.

Any thoughts?

Comment: isnt jrebel alone enough? intellij uses hotswap, which is far inferior to it.

Comment: Sometimes it can happen that the IDE debugger hangs if hotswap is performed by the 3rd party agent (as in case with JRebel). With JRebel you can skip the hotswap operation (or disable it in settings) - JRebel will do the hot update just fine.